# Conctenating two collections in a liquid assignment

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Based on [this tutorial](https://www.sylvaindurand.org/making-jekyll-multilingual/), I built a multi-lingual Jekyll site. In every page, the following code links to the versions of the same page in different languages:

```
    {% assign pages=site.pages | where:"id", page.id | sort: 'path' %}
    {% for p in pages %}
    <a href="{{ p.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}" class="{{ p.lang }}"><img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/images/{{ p.lang }}.png" alt="This page in {{ p.lang }}"/></a>
    {% endfor %}
```

This works well, but I want to do the same in pages that belong to other collections besides "site.pages". For example, I have a collection called "site.TOPICS". I would like to replace the first line with something like:

```
    {% assign pages=site.pages + site.TOPICS | where:"id", page.id | sort: 'path' %}
```

or:

```
    {% assign pages=site.EVERYTHING | where:"id", page.id | sort: 'path' %}
```

But this does not work.

Is there a way to concatenate two collections? Or alternatively, to access all objects in the site regardless of type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now (Jekyll 3.1.x I don't think you can do it.

I found: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/427

Which seems to show it is coming - this is an issue that looks like it is solved in Liquid, but a higher version of liquid that Jekyll uses.

I also found this: https://github.com/mpc-hc/mpc-hc.org/commit/624a4bf63710ce00d98c80f8b3655a71c0468747#diff-23a9de36055c1aa13a62d73b9c318ebd

where parker says this is a potential 4.x feature.

It looks like if you have more than one collection you could use `site.documents` to do this, I did a little test and while it sounds like site.documents is all docs in the site, it looks like it is really all docs in collections.

There is a `push` filter that maybe you could use to push one array into another, but I don't think it is really made to add 2 arrays together.

In the meantime I think just duplicating your code and having one for pages and one for collections would work. If I understand correctly your id would only be found if it matched so one would find something the other wouldn't.

Comment: Using "site.pages" and "site.documents"  works great. There is duplication, but only twice. Thanks!

Comment: I think there is also site.collections. It sure sounds like site.documents should be all documents, not just collections. Glad you got it to work!